# *ngFor output filtering by pipes

Tags: angular

I have a HTML construction like:

```
<div *ngFor="#notification of notifications"
      [innerHTML]="notification | notificationHTML">
</div>
```

And a `notificationHTML` pipe:

```
transform(notification: string, args: any[]): any {
var example: any;
this._service.GetExample(notification)
     .subscribe(e => {
         example = e;
      });
return "<span>" + example + "</span>";
}
```

The problem is that `example` variable is equal to `undefined`, because function `GetExample` does not have time to execute on time. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below,

Return an Observable from your `Pipe` transform and then use `async` pipe

**Component template**

```
 <div *ngFor="#notification of notifications"
   [innerHTML]="notification | notificationHTML | async">
 </div>
```

**Pipe**

```
  notificationObservable: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  transform(notification: string, args: any[]): any {
   this._service.GetExample(notification)
      .subscribe(e => {
         this.notificationObservable.next("<span>" + e+ "</span>");
     });
   return notificationObservable;
  }
```

Here is the [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/TOfEnAR7CD1Hf3nSmnDH?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume `GetExample` returns an observable of some sort. If so, there's no guarantee that your subscription will be triggered before `transform` returns. Either you'll have to make the `GetExample` method synchronous, or you'll have to cache the value returned by the subscription and use it whenever `transform` gets called.